# Scheduling a Python Script via Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler

Observe the following Python script, "Script.py":

```
import subprocess
src_directory = 'Z:\z_7z\Some_Directory'
zip_file_name = 'Test.7z'
cmd = ['7z', 'a', zip_file_name, src_directory, '-mx9']
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

My intent is to schedule a Python script using Windows Task Scheduler.  I have successfully done this using other Python scripts before.  However, I am unable to execute the script shown above via scheduling.  I am unsure as to whether this is a Windows Task Scheduler problem or a Python problem, but here is what I know:

"Script.py", as shown above, is a script for running a 7zip compression on a "Some_Directory" directory.  The script itself and the 7z.exe application which it is invoking are both stored in the "Y:\z_7z" directory.

The script seems to be working fine when executed manually.  I can double-click on the script and it will execute properly.  Also, I can execute the script from the command line via the following command:

```
Y:\z_7z\Script.py
```

However, I cannot execute the script manually by navigating to the "C:\Python27" directory and attempting the following:

```
python Y:\z_7z\Script.py
```

This yields the following error:

```
Line 5 in module subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, ...)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Provided all of that information, the real problem I am having is that Windows Task Scheduler cannot execute this script (Last Run Result = 0x1).  I have tried various Windows Task Scheduler configurations, including the one which seems to be ideal which goes as follows:

- Program/script: "C:\Python27\python.exe"
- Add arguments (optional): "Y:\z_7z\Script.py"
- Run whether user is logged on or not

Again, I have scheduled other Python scripts before which have run successfully.  This Windows Task Scheduler task seems to be configured properly.  I browsed through some of the more advanced settings and did not find anything suspicious with this particular task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't just launch `7z`. Provide the full path to the executable.

   cmd = [r'C:\Program Files\7zip\7z.exe', 'a', zip_file_name, src_directory, '-mx9']
   Would work, considering that `C:\Program Files\7zip\7z.exe` is the executable path.
2. Try not running the `python` process with the script as an argument. Run the python script itself.
3. Your `zip_file_name` is relative. I'm not sure the argument is a filename. It may be a path. In that case, the .7z file may be created on `C:\Windows\System32`. To fix it, set `zip_file_name` to be a full path.

Comment: After making that change, the Windows Task Scheduler Last Run Result = "The operation completed successfully. (0x0)".  Therefore, it seems like everything is setup correctly now on the Task Scheduler side.  However, the script does not do anything.  I can run the script manually though, and it works great.  Also, it may be worth noting that I am closing all programs to test the scheduled task.  I am testing it while being logged in as well as while not being logged in.  Same results.  Successful task, seemingly unsuccessful script.

Comment: What you suggested in (3) solved the issue.  I tried (2) as well, but that did not seem to make a difference.  Once (3) was done, the script ran whether I did (2) or not.