# Issues launching a python script with Windows 7 Task Scheduler

Tags: python

I have a python script that incorporates subprocesses. I want it to run at a given time, so I set up a task to launch the .py script. However, it does not run...I viewed the history of the event and it appears to have "started" and closed all at 3:30:00 pm. So nothing really ever happened. I have also tried starting it in a batch file, that does not work with the task scheduler either. However, both the standalone script and the batch file work independently of the task scheduler just fine. Has anyone seen this or have any idea what I need to do to fix this issue?

Comment: I had the same problem. I have abandoned Task Scheduler and am using the [`schedule`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule) module.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073205/scheduling-a-python-script-via-windows-task-scheduler?rq=1?

Comment: @bernie what if you wanted the actual python script to only start at a certain time every day. How does internal python code effect the windows environment without running?

Comment: IIUC: you keep an instance of the schedule module running at all times and then at a set time it runs your Python code.